# Do machine.config/web.config in .NET Framework 3.0/3.5 and .NET Framewor 1.1/1.0 cascade?

Tags: asp.net

I made a change in my machine.config for a 1.1 application and then later I upgraded the application to .Net Framework 3.0/3.5. Will that configuration change still apply or do I have to make that change in my local web.config for the 2.0 machine.config/web.config? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Frameworks 2.0 - 3.5 all use the .NET 2.0 machine.config.

As a result, you will need to update the 2.0 config file.